# Ajax post 404 on POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, email, post

I am trying to send a test email using node.

My server code index.js looks like this:

```
var http = require("http"),
    express = require('express'),
    nodemailer = require('nodemailer'),
     bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {

    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var message = req.body.message;

    var mailOpts, smtpTrans;

    smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: "email@gmail.com",
            pass: "password"
        }
    });

    mailOpts = {
        from: name + ' &lt;' + email + '&gt;', //grab form data from the request body object
        to: 'cmatsoukis@gmail.com',
        subject: "Website Contact",
        text: message
    };

    smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, response) {
        //Email not sent
        if (error) {
            res.send(false);
        }
            //Yay!! Email sent
        else {
            res.send(true);
        }
    });

});

app.listen(1337, '127.0.0.2');
```

This is my ajax code when I submit the form

```
var form = $("form#contact_form");
form.submit(function () {
    event.preventDefault();

    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var msg = $('#message').val();

    var info = {"name" : name, "email": email, "message" : msg} 

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.2:1337',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(info),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        jsonpCallback: 'callback', // this is not relevant to the POST anymore
        //dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            MailSuccess()
            lightSpeed();

        },
        error: function () {
            MailFail();
        }
    });
});
```

I am getting the error **`POST http://127.0.0.2:1337/ 404 (Not Found)`**

I do not think I have the url correct. I have `app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {` But I do not this that is correct. And shouldn't I put a file name in the `url: 'http://127.0.0.2:1337',`?

I believe I have everything else correct. Please let me know.

Comment: You also did not declare `event`...

Comment: Yikes, I had it in. Must have been an accident.

Comment: try adding `/contact` at end of your URL in Ajax, it should work.

Comment: Okay cool! I got a 500 error now :) more learning!

Answer (score 2):

You've registered a POST handler for `'/contact'` but you are making the request to `'/'`.

Since you haven't told express what to do for `'/'` it returns a Not Found.

Make the two paths match.